# Django: Problems embedding tinyMCE into my non-flatpage model

Tags: django, tinymce

I got tinyMCE working for flat pages by copying the change_form.html file and embedding a script element.

I followed the directions [here](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/AddWYSIWYGEditor) but still have issues. I added this snippet to my Entry model:

```
class Entry( models.Model ):

    class Admin:
        # various admin options are here
        js = (
                '/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',
                '/appmedia/admin/js/textareas.js',
            )
```

When I view source in my add entry admin page ( after restarting Apache2 ) I don't see the above referenced js files anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directions you linked to are *very* old, and in particular date back to before the 'newforms-admin' changes were made. You need to add the `js` tuple to your admin class's inner `Media` class, as described [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-media-definitions).

Answer (score 0):

Ended up resorting to `django-tinymce`, had to modify my app's admin.py and define a class for the AdminForm, override the form attribute with my newly created class, and tinyMCE finally showed up.